# PHP shortcode yields unexpected result

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

This is an attempt to create a PHP shortcode within the context of a WordPress plug-in, following instructions [here](https://www.wplab.com/create-custom-listing-shortcodes-for-wp-lister/):

```
function echo_postage_cost($html, $item, $images) {
    global $product;
    $sku = get_post_meta( $item['post_id'], '_sku', true );

    if ($sku == "/(^SY-).+/"){
      $postage_cost = "\$25";
    } else {
      $postage_cost = "FREE" ;
    }

    $html = str_replace( '[[postage_cost]]', '$postage_cost', $html );

    return $html;
}

add_filter( 'wplister_process_template_html', 'echo_postage_cost', 10, 3 );
```

One is then supposed to use `[[postage_cost]]` to invoke the function's output.

However, the output is always "FREE", even when the value of `_sku` is "SY-DB9-03-MM", and we expect "$25".  Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are developing locally and have error logging enabled. Try adding `error_log( print_r( $sku, true ));` after the `$sku` variable in the shortcode. Also this is some custom, non WP filter that you are hooking into, not sure how this filter works or what it does tbh...

Comment: So where do you parse the regular expression? Shouldn't you use preg_match or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if ($sku == "/(^SY-).+/"){
```

should be:

```
if (preg_match("/(^SY-).+/", $sku)){
```

or simpler:

```
if (preg_match("/^SY-/", $sku)){
```

Comment: Thank you Toto, this answer is correct, but decorum dictates I award the answer to the one who got in first and the timestamp shows @Brijesh Borad got in 1 minute before you.  ^^'  I am very grateful all the same.

Comment: @ptrcao: You're welcome. But **I**'ve given the answer 1 min before (14:14:20 the other answer: 14:15:15)

Answer (score 3):

Please try with this code,

```
function echo_postage_cost($html, $item, $images) {
    global $product;
    $sku = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_sku', true );

    if (preg_match('/(^SY-).+/', $sku)){
      $postage_cost = "\$25";
    } else {
      $postage_cost = "FREE" ;
    }

    $html = str_replace( '[[postage_cost]]', '$postage_cost', $html );

    return $html;
}

add_filter( 'wplister_process_template_html', 'echo_postage_cost', 10, 3 );
```